# Dropdownlist loaded from function or method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, object, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist which I constantly use.
I wrote a method to load this dropdown.
Though when I call the method only the Text part of the item is passed.
This is the method

```
Public Shared Function ddlLoadResumes() As DropDownList
    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
    Dim ddSelectResumeList As New DropDownList
    Dim dtResumes As New DataTable()

    Dim comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("usr_SelectResumeList", conn)
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    comm.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Membership.GetUser().UserName

    Try
        Dim daResumes As New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
        conn.Open()
        daResumes.Fill(dtResumes)

        ddSelectResumeList.DataSource = dtResumes
        ddSelectResumeList.DataTextField = "ResumeName"
        ddSelectResumeList.DataValueField = "Res_ID"
        ddSelectResumeList.DataBind()


        ' Handle the error
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        conn.Close()

    End Try


    Return ddSelectResumeList

End Function
```

and this is how I call it

```
ddSelectResume.DataSource = MailClass.ddlLoadResumes.Items
ddSelectResume.DataBind()

Dim ltitem As ListItem
        For Each ltitem In ddSelectResume.Items
            Response.Write(ltitem.Value + "-----" + ltitem.Text)
        Next   returns only the text part
```

I need both DataTextField and DataValueField.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This seems like kind of an odd approach.  One thing to resolve your issue would be to just set the ddSelectResume equal to the DropDownList object your Function is returning:

```
ddSelectResume = MailClass.ddlLoadResumes

Dim ltitem As ListItem
        For Each ltitem In ddSelectResume.Items
            Response.Write(ltitem.Value + "-----" + ltitem.Text)
        Next
```

Though I think a better approach would be to just have "ddlLoadResumes return the DataTable (dtResumes), and set that as the datasoure of ddSelectResumes (you'd still have to set the DataTextField and DataValueField properties).

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work, @Tzvei?  Perhaps you could just try load the Items collection?  Like `ddSelectResume.Items = MailClass.ddlLoadResumes.Items`.

Comment: What I mean is that the ddSelectResume is empty after bind().  
ddSelectResume expects a datasource

Comment: @Tzvei Why would you call `Bind()`? It was already bound in `ddlLoadResumes`.

Comment: i specified in my first post:    
    ddSelectResume.DataSource = MailClass.ddlLoadResumes.Items
    ddSelectResume.DataBind()  This works but only for the TextField

Comment: OK  
I used the dataAdapter as you suggested and it works fine.  
I would have preferred my initial method (more elegant)

Comment: Hey, @Tzvei.  FYI - if this answer helped you solve your problem, you can mark it as the "accepted answer" by checking the empty checkmark box next to it.  See ["How does accepting an answer work?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for more information.